# The sort-by-XXX-button

Tags: java, swing, sorting

Is there an easy, simple, way to do create buttons for sorting lists by name, size etc just like these:

http://lh6.ggpht.com/_SU7V9sPwn1o/TUmfW_qBiCI/AAAAAAAABTo/9CJYApWzMfI/s1600/Task-manager-IE-memory7.png

(Image name, User namne, SPU etc.)

I want to do a list with such buttons but I assume there must be an easy way to implement there buttons.

PS, using swing!

Comment: In that case, the JTable would sort it automatically when you click the headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this by implementing [JTables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) using java swing.

Check out these [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: This is correct, if alfabetical and numerical sorting is enough you can use the default sorting capabilities with `setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)`. Keep in mind that after a table is sorted the table index of a row (visual position) and the model index (internal data position) are not the same anymore and you have to convert one into the other as needed using the methods  `convertRowIndexToView(modelRowIndex)` and `convertRowIndexToModel(viewRowIndex)`.